# Is there a name for a group where elements either commute or anti-commute?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

An abelian group is a group where each element commutes with any other element in the set, so $ab=ba$.

I was reading the wikipedia article on the [anticommutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutative_property). I think this could be generalised to arbitrary groups as follows:

> Suppose $G$ embed into the group of units of some ring $R$ (so for $g\in G$ the element $-g$ makes sense, as $-1$ is a unit). Then $a, b\in G$ *anticommute* if $ab=-ba$.

Another, possibly more general, interpretation is:

> Let $-1$ be a distinguished central element of order two in $G$ (so for $g\in G$ the element $-g=g(-1)=(-1)g$ makes sense). Say that $a, b\in G$ *anticommute with respect to $-1$* if $ab=-ba$.

I was therefore wondering: Is there a specific name for a group where any two elements in the group either commute or anti-commute (with respect to a fixed element $-1$)? That is, for $a,b$ in $G$ either $ab=ba$ or $ab=-ba$.

Comment: How do you define anti-commute in a group?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner please see my edit.

Comment: What is $-1$ in a group?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, sorry, please have a look at it again.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $a * b = (b * a)^{-1}$?

Comment: And what is the $-$ in $-(b \ast a)$?  The inverse?  $(b\ast a)^{-1}$ would be more common notation.

Comment: @NateEldredge, sure, that is a good thought.

Comment: Note that if $(a\star b)=(b\star a)^{-1}$ for all $a,b$ then $g^2=1$ for all $g$, so $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g$, so $(a\star b)=(b\star a)$; an 'anticommutative' group is a commutative group.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I am more looking into the definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutative_property)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, but does this answer the question? We may either have $a * b = b * a$ or $a * b = (b * a)^{-1}$. The question mentions operations are either commutative or anti-commutative.

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury agreed — I think there's actually an interesting question lurking here! But OP seems somewhat confused about what anticommutativity means in a group context (see the several revisions to the question, along with the usage of the phrase 'anticommutative group', which is what I was specifically trying to point to).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, that is true. I don't have lots of details about it, that's why I was adapting to the changes.

Comment: Note carefully the definition in the Wikipedia article is not about "anticommutativity" of the group operation itself, but of some mapping from a (power of a) set *into* an abelian group.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki $(a \circ b )= (b \circ a )^{-1} \implies (a^{2} \circ b^{2})= e $ from this it can't be say that $g^2=e$ unless the group is commutative. So, how do you say a anti commutative operation is a commutative operation?

Comment: @Alearner take $b=e$.

Comment: @jgon why should I take, $a,b$ are arbitrary here , right?

Comment: I’m pretty sure there is no specific name; there are certainly such groups: $Q_8$ has the property, if I haven’t messed up my mental calculations.

Comment: @Alearner I didn't say that an anticommutative operation is a commutative operation; I said an anticommutative _group_ must be a commutative group, for the reason that jgon mentioned. As I noted, the question properly framed is an interesting one.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki  the reason that jgon mentioned, it didn't work as I say in my comment. Please notice that. Taking $b=e$ , implies $e^2$ have more than one inverse, as $a^2$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @Alearner If we have an 'anticommutative group', i.e. something that obeys the laws of a group and in which any two elements anticommute (i.e., $(a\star b)=(b\star a)^{-1}$), then 'any two elements' includes the identity — so taking $b=e$, we have $a=a^{-1}$ for any element $a$. This implies that $(b\star a)^{-1}=(b\star a)$ (since $b\star a$ is an element of the group), so we have $a\star b=b\star a$ for arbitrary elements $a, b$; in other words, a group that satisfies the anticommutative law is _also_ commutative.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki so, what about $Q_8$?

Comment: @Alearner That doesn't satisfy the anticommutative law for _all_ elements; it is not an 'anticommutative group'.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki can you please show,, which elements didn't satisfy the anticommutative law

Comment: @Alearner $(ei)=i\neq i^{-1} = (ie)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki in your opinion, can all abelian groups be anti commutative group? It is question.

Comment: @Alearner No; a group that's anticommutative must also satisfy $a^2=e$ for all members of the group. But a commutative group in which each element has order $2$ is also anticommutative (trivially so).

Comment: @YCor I am not sure that your edit preserves the meaning of the question. It certainly makes the question interesting and more focused, but it also isolates the other answer.

Comment: Incidentally, I am surprised that noone has suggested that the question be interpreted as "$G$ embeds into the group of units of some ring $R$ such that for all $a, b\in G$ either $ab=ba$ or $ab=-ba$" (as $a$, $b$ and $-1$ are units, $-ba$ is also a unit). To me, this definition most closely follows the definition from the wikipedia article (and is a restriction of @QiaochuYuan's interpretation).

Comment: @user1729 Actually I've seen the other answer before editing as this sounded for me as the only possible reasonable meaning (and I still believe it, as other interpretation make reference to some extra structure such as distinguished element or embedding into a ring), and before seriously thinking at the question (and post an answer). Retrospectively I'm a bit embarrassed as it might be a way to arrange my answer to be the right one. Feel free to revert to the previous, unclear formulation of the question.

Comment: @YCor Well, both questions are interesting. How about we revert this question, and then I ask the "$ab=ba$ or $ab=(ba)^{-1}$" question in new question, and you can post your answer there?

Comment: @user1729 I see (I stupidly thought my interpretation covers Qiaochu's but actually no: there are groups satisfying Qiaochu's condition but not mine). That the OP refuses to clarify (only linking to a page which gives a definition not meaningful for an abstract group) is problematic indeed. You might revert to the question and add explicitly Qiaochu's interpretation. If you post the other one I'll copy my answer and delete it here.

Comment: @YCor Okay, I've written the new question. I called $ab=(ba)^{-1}$ "twisted-commute" to differentiate it from "anti-commute". No idea if "twisted-commute" has another meaning though.

Comment: @user1729, I appreciate your edit. It is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @user1729: the definition you give in terms of embedding into a ring is equivalent to mine (in one direction, adjoining $-1$ gives a central extension, and in the other direction, we can use the twisted group algebra).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, I wondered if it was, but was unsure about the "other direction". Could you maybe add that in to your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to make sense of this question as follows. Let $G$ be a group together with a distinguished central element of order $2$ which we call $-1$; we'll write the product $(-1)a$ as $-a$. Say that two elements $a, b \in G$ *anticommute* if $ab = -ba$. Then we have, more or less by definition:

> **Claim:** Every pair of elements in $G$ either commutes or anticommutes iff the quotient $G/\{ 1, -1 \}$ is abelian.

So the desired groups are precisely the [central extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension) of abelian groups by $C_2$. These groups are [2-step nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group), and in the finite case every such group must have the form $G = G_1 \times G_2$ where $G_1$ is an abelian group of odd order and $G_2$ is a central extension of an abelian $2$-group by $C_2$.

The two smallest nonabelian examples of such groups are the quaternion group $Q_8$ and the dihedral group $D_8$, which are central extensions of $C_2 \times C_2$ by $C_2$. See the Wikipedia article on [extraspecial groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_special_group#p_=_2) for more. $D_8$ is also isomorphic to the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_2) $H_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

The group algebra $k[G]$ of such a group has a distinguished quotient where we identify $-1 \in G$ with the actual element $-1 \in k[G]$ (apologies for the abuse of notation); this is a certain twisted group algebra of $G / \{ 1, -1 \}$. Applying this construction to the quaternion group $Q_8$ over $k = \mathbb{R}$ produces the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is very poorly written; I might edit it.

Comment: I edited the Wikipedia article on anticommutativity.