# How to define a Lie group that is a Riemannian manifold and has an anticommutative group operation?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I want to know how to define a Lie group that is also a Riemannian manifold and has a group operation that is anticommutative, $a * b = -b * a$ for all elements $a$ and $b$ in the group $(G, *)$.

I know that a Lie group is a smooth manifold that also has a group structure, such that the group operations of multiplication and inversion are smooth maps. I also know that we can define a bi-invariant riemannian metric on it (if it's compact). But how can I combine these two concepts and also impose the anticommutativity condition?

Is there a general way to construct such a Lie group? Or are there any examples of such a Lie group that are known or studied in the literature? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the minus sign here. If we assume that you mean the group inverse by the minus sign, then $ab = (ba)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all elements in the group. If we take $b = 1$, the unit, it follows that all elemnts $a$ satisfy $a = a^{-1}$, so $a^2 = 1$.

Comment: @AkselBergfeldt I mean that it is noncommutative (anticommutative)

Comment: Again, take $b=1$, so $a=a1=-1a=-a$. Whatever you mean by the minus sign, we get $a=-a$ for all $a$ in the group. It follows that $ab=-ba=ba$, so the group is commutative.

Comment: The property of being noncommutative (or non-Abelian) of a group is that there exists element $a,b$ such that $ab \neq ba$. Anticommutativity, I believe, is something different, namely what you wrote; $ab = -ba$, with some appropriate meaning to the minus sign. If you only have a group structure, then the group inverse is the only involution, so this is what must be meant with the minus sign. Then you get what I wrote. I do not think there is any nontrivial Lie group with this property. Maybe you mean something different with the minus sign?

Comment: @AkselBergfeldt Sorry, I meant by "$ab = -ba$" $a * b = -b * a$ where $*$ is an operation that comes from the anti-abelian group $(G, *)$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808941/949989). @Esmond: how do you deifine an anti-abelian group? The [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator) in a group is $$[a,b]=a^{-1}\,b^{-1}a\,b\,.$$ The group is abelian iff  this commutator is the identity of the group. The same WP article mentions that to have an anti-commutator $\{a,b\}$ the group should also be a ring.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think that a anti-abelian group is a module on the ring $\theta_i \mathbb Z$ ($= { ... -\theta, 0 , \theta , 2\theta ... } $) of integers where $\theta_i$ is a grassmannian variable, as all modules on $\mathbb Z$ are abelian groups. Do you understand ? Maybe not because it's not something that one can define...

Comment: @Esmond - Isn't your ring just $\mathbb Z$ with the trivial "multiplication" $a*b=0$ (since $\theta\theta=0$) (and with the standard addition)? Or do you have more than one $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

The OP clarified in a *comment* that by "anticommutative" he means "noncommutative".  If so, the simplest example of a noncommutative Lie group is the 3-sphere $S^3$.  A natural product structure arises from viewing the 3-sphere as the unit sphere in the quaternions $\mathbb H$.  Here $H=\mathbb R^4$ as a real vector space, but the point is the existence of a noncommutative product operation among elements of $\mathbb H$.  Thus, let $1,i,j,k$ denote the standard basis.  We define the product of quaternions to be real-linear, and also satisfy the relations $ij=-ji, jk=-kj, ki=-ik$, as well as $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.  Note that $i,j\in S^3$ and they visibly don't commute.

I see now that there is a new edit which re-insists on anticommutativity.  This is confused because the unit element in the group commutes with every other element.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez.  Agreed.  Being a differential geometer, however, I prefer as geometric an example as possible :-)